# IE hover on link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, hover

I have a problem with a `<a>` tag on hover function.

```
<a href='#' onClick='javascript:showPrev();'class='prev'> </a>
```

The problem is in CSS code. If I set `background-color` in both `a{}` and `a:hover{}` the image will be visible. Otherwise, if there is no `background-color` or set to `none`, the image wont show on hover.

Here is my CSS

```
a.next {
  outline:none;
  position: absolute; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  color:black; 
  z-index: 800; 
  left: 534px;  
  top: 0px; 
  width: 266px; 
  height: 600px; 
  display: inline;
}

a.prev {
  outline:none;
  position: absolute; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  color:black; 
  z-index: 800; 
  left: 0px;  
  float:left; 
  top: 0px;  
  width: 266px; 
  height: 600px; 
  display: inline;
}

#slideshow a.next:hover {   
  outline:none;
  position: absolute; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  color:black; 
  z-index: 800; 
  left: 534px;  
  top: 0px; 
  width: 266px; 
  height: 600px; 
  display: inline; 
  background:url(../images/next.png) 90% 65% no-repeat;
}

#slideshow a.prev:hover {   
  outline:none;
  position: absolute; 
  text-decoration:none;    
  color:black; 
  z-index: 800; 
  left: 0px;  
  float:left; 
  top: 0px;  
  width: 266px; 
  height: 600px; 
  display: inline; 
  background:url(../images/prev.png) 10% 65%  no-repeat;
}
```

Does anybody know what might be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give us the URL that exhibits the problem, please.

Comment: http://closecurly.kodingen.com/bm/project.html?n=COVERED_CLUSTER&p=1&i=33

Here is the link, you can test on chrome for example and see how its supposed to be. And then ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does seem to be some weird IE issue that means the a tags remain behind the image unless you set a background property, and I can't work out why at the moment...

BUT...

You can get around this by copying your background attributes from the :hover states to the 'normal' a states, and then adding a large negative background position, so they are effectively hidden until they are hovered over, e.g.:

```
a.next {
  outline:none;
  position: absolute; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  color:black; 
  z-index: 800; 
  left: 534px;  
  top: 0px; 
  width: 266px; 
  height: 600px; 
  display: inline;

  background:url(../images/next.png) 90% -1000% no-repeat;
}
```

This should work

Comment: Thanks dude. I never thought for this approach. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `\` just before `#slideshow a.next:hover{` it's probably messing up IE's effort at parsing your CSS

Comment: unlikely to be the problem as he mentioned that adding `background-color` solves it. (unless he's wrong, obviously)

Comment: It was a typo while posting. I have removed it now. Its not in the live code though.